# Invalid block tag : 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: python, html, django

l get stuck in this error. l'm fresh user of `Django` and l m learning it by following steps on Youtube channel. l did everything same but l got this block tag error.
here is layout1 html content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{ % block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
{ % block content %}   {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

index html content:

```
{% extends "layout/layout1.html"%}


{% block title %}The Video page{% endblock %}


{ % block content %}


<h1>This is a html</h1>

<p>This is a p tag</p>

<a href="http://www.noobmovies.com">Click me!</a>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/72/Anthony_Raneri.jpg"/>

{% endblock % }
```

views.py content:

```
from django.template.response   import TemplateResponse


# Create your views here.
def video(request):

    return TemplateResponse (request,"video/index.html",{})
```

how can l handle this problem? as l did double-check to make sure everything is typed same like Youtube channel and normally ,l did not get where l did a mistake.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Django didn't recognise your starting block tag, because you have a space between the `{` and the `%`.

You also have the same error in both start and end tags in the other template file.

Answer (score 14):

You simply have typos.

You should have `{%` not `{ %`, and you got those typos in both of templates.

So you need to have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {% block content %}   {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

and

```
{% extends "layout/layout1.html"%}


{% block title %}The Video page{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
  <h1>This is a html</h1>

  <p>This is a p tag</p>

  <a href="http://www.noobmovies.com">Click me!</a>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/72/Anthony_Raneri.jpg"/>

{% endblock %}
```

NOTE: don't forget about identations in *html* files, it makes code more readable.

Comment: Clear and totally understandable. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

If none of the previous answers worked for you, try the following:

You are most likely using a base.html file and have the static css being loaded on the top `{% load static %}` and the problem for me was that I needed to also load this in my other template file.

I'm using Django 2.0.3 and this solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

For me it was the issue of using `i18n` **without putting** the `{% load i18n %}` inside the template file (I only put it in the base template)

Answer (score 3):

For me it was emacs breaking the lines up when I copied the template over, so

```
{% endif
```

was on one line and

```
%}
```

was on the next line.  These need to be together on one line, and

```
{{ variable_name }}
```

too.

Answer (score 3):

in my case use `{% load static %}` after `{% extends 'base.html' %}` solved.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had a <img> tag that had if and else in it and this solution helped me.

Answer (score 3):

I got this error because I mixed up `{% %}` and `{{ }}`. I had:

```
<title>{% user.name %} ({% user.id %})</title>
```

When I should have had:

```
<title>{{ user.name }} ({{ user.id }})</title>
```

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was with `{% extends %}`, it was extend.

Answer (score 2):

In your Html template, ensure you `{% load static %}` just after your `{% block content %}`
before using it in the template

Answer (score 2):

In my case,
`{% csrf token %}` instead of this `{% csrf_token %}` solved.

If you are missed _ (underscore) in code then also you will got this error.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @gal-bracha answer, for me the problem was caused by including a template inside another (through the `{% include %}` tag) and both templates making use of a `{% trans "some text" %}` tag. In this case, the `{% load i18n %}` must be written in **both** the including and in the included templates.

Answer (score 0):

Not to answer this specific question, but to share my case which gave the same error:
In my case this same error been caused because I forgot to add the url in the link  reference name:

```
href="{% url 'allblogs' %}".  worked.
```

while error was received when url was missed like below:

```
href="{% 'allblogs' %}". Error been generated.
```

Answer (score 0):

if you encounter this:
**Invalid block tag on line 172: 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?**
Check:
Any part of your code commented, check if `{% endfor %}` has been repeated.
If it is repeated delete one especially the commented section.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i used replaced `{% csrf token %}` with `{% csrf_token %}` and it seemed to work.

In any template that uses a `POST` form, use the `csrf_token` tag inside the `<form>` element if the form is for an internal URL, e.g.:

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
```

This should not be done for `POST` forms that target external URLs, since that would cause the CSRF token to be leaked, leading to a vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

This also happens when you forget putting your phrase between quotes.

```
{% trans My phrase %}
```

instead of

```
{% trans "My phrase" %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently even double space between **{% endblock** and **content  %}** is also a problem in version **4.1.7**
Corrected to a single space and it worked fine.i.e:

```
{% endblock  content %} # failed. Note the double space
{% endblock content %} # worked fine
```