# Django error Invalid block tag on line 21: 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag? How do i fix it

Tags: python, html, css, django

```
{% extends 'miromi_first/base_template.html' %} {% load static %} {% block
content %}

<img src="{% static 'miromi_first/images/miromi_logo.png' %}" />

<div class="topnav">
  <div class="topnav-right">
    <a href="#about">Login</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="main-stuff">
  <h2>Welcome to Our fashion app</h2>
  <h4>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus voluptates
    nihil corrupti incidunt hic, quasi fugiat quaerat esse veniam sed,
    blanditiis voluptatem saepe velit eligendi voluptas dicta architecto
    doloremque magnam.
  </h4>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

I try to load the image i want using this but get the error : Invalid block tag on line 22: 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag? in django (if i remoce the load static and image URL stuff it works fine

Comment: Do you have `django.contrib.staticfiles` app installed?

Comment: Are you added in  `miromi_first/base_template.html`  static css being loaded on the top `{% load static %}`.?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid block tag : 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39935578/invalid-block-tag-endblock-did-you-forget-to-register-or-load-this-tag)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have added a new line after block which is causing the problem.

Try moving the `{% block content %}` to a new line, and make sure that the complete tag is on a single line.