# Why is Django giving did you forget to register or load this tag error?

Tags: python, django, windows, pycharm

I have a working Django app that has started giving me a template block error on my Windows 11 development PC:

> Invalid block tag on line 17: 'endblock', expected 'endblock' or 'endblock stylesheets'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

I looked at this stackoverflow article:
[Invalid block tag : 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39935578/invalid-block-tag-endblock-did-you-forget-to-register-or-load-this-tag), but I don't have the typo that that article discusses.  It is in a base.html template:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
{% load static %}
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" href="{% static 'assets/img/orange-img.png' %}" type="image/x-icon">

  <title>
    Clever - {% block title %}{% endblock %}
  </title> 

  <!-- Specific Page CSS goes HERE  -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/blue_theme.css' %}">
  {% block stylesheets %}

  {% endblock  stylesheets %}

</head>
<body class="hold-transition {% block body_class %}{% endblock body_class %}; w3-theme-l4">

  {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
  <div style="text-align: center">
      {% include 'includes/footer.html' %}
  </div>

  <!-- Specific Page JS goes HERE  -->
  {% block javascripts %}
  {% endblock javascripts %}
  {% include 'session_security/all.html' %}

</body>
</html>
```

The error gets generated on line 17:  {% endblock  stylesheets %}.  I have tried putting the block and endblock on the same line, it gives me that same error with the different line number.  I don't have a space between the curly braces and the percentage signs.  I am running this with python 3.11.1 and Django 3.2.16 on my Windows PC.  I tried it with python 3.7.3 with the same results.  I have the app running on a Ubuntu instance with python 3.10.6 and Django 3.2.16, and it works.  For what it's worth, I use PyCharm on my Windows PC.

Any suggestions?

Thanks--

Al

Answer (score 0):

In the immortal words of Gilda Radner--"never mind".  I had a typo in another template that was causing the error in this template...  The lesson learned is don't use vim when you're so tired that you don't notice you're in insert mode when you do a ':w'...

--Al